# Can we improve on "Do you do hallway usability testing?" in the Joel Test?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

The Joel Test questions that have become standard now for employers posting jobs advertised on SO. I generally agree with this, and feel they are useful guides to which parts of a developer's work are well supported by a company. I have of course read the [original blog article describing the test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html).

Most of the requirements are quite general, and stated in terms of "you really need this or something like this" - e.g. a daily build can be implemented in many ways depending on the nature of a product. I can count my company's daily smoke test (which deploys a version of a web service before testing it) as being the same thing. Likewise a bug database or schedule can take many forms, and be geared towards different team approaches - agile (in its different guises), waterfall etc. A spec can be a formal document written by a chief architect and signed off by the CTO, or it can be the user stories in a Scrum process.

But I always wince slightly when I see "Do you do hallway usability testing?" - it is very specific, in fact smacks of one-true-wayism. It also stands out as the only question where a prospective employer cannot point to something that exists (a written policy, a system, the office itself for noise levels) as evidence.

For instance, I do on occasion grab one of my colleagues for a 10 minute design discussion - does that count? It would seem odd to me that it did, it is not something that is in any way codified or required by the company or team. It seems hard for a company to claim that they "officially" do this. I am therefore naturally suspect of any Joel Test result which has that item ticked - what exactly are these people doing, or what artefacts they have in order to claim to meet the requirement? An item on the job description that says the employee is responsible for talking things through with their peers? The fact that Fred and Bob like to argue design on coffee break?

Surely the goal of this last question in the test is that interface designs (whether public class APIs, web services, or user interfaces) are checked and validated before investing major effort into coding. There is a wide range of approaches taken in practice which can be informal to inherent part of development process.

*Is there a better way of phrasing this question in the Joel Test, such that it is more inclusive of other design validation approaches, and it results in something that a candidate could verify during an interview?*

Answer (score -1):

(Self answer)

No I do not think there is a better way to phrase the question. How designs are arrived at varies a lot between companies, and formalised design processes that *could* point to business artefacts are not necessarily better than informal processes such as the suggested "hallway usability testing" or [guerilla usability testing](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-art-of-guerrilla-usability-testing/). There is no easy way to ask for design artefacts such as documentation or databases, in the same way as suggesting there should be a source control system or a bug database.

However, right now the question is a bit of an outlier. Companies that can honestly say they put effort up-front into validating designs cannot answer "yes", and companies that answer "yes" can do so without a candidate being able to see anything that verifies the fact.

I have the following problems with it:

- As an employer that does validate designs, I cannot answer "yes" unless I specifically do "hallway usability testing", even though my approach to design does help make a better product and happier developers.
- As a developer seeing a "yes" answer to the question, I don't really get a sense of what it means. In fact, mainly it raises my suspicions that the employer is taking some small piece of history (such as one developer checked with another team briefly once whether the interface looked OK) and using it gain a tick mark.

The question should IMO be removed from the Joel Test.